# Error running simple program in NetBeans 9.0

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to use NetBeans for a JDBC project. However, I'm getting runtime errors when I try to compile. I decided to try a "hello world" project and I couldn't get that to run also. I'm in NetBeans 9.0 with Java JDK 10.0.2.

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:1)
C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\dev\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\dev\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

xml debug:<call-java classname="@{classname}" classpath="@{classpath}" modulename="@{modulename}" modulepath="@{modulepath}">

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Hello");
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Your build failed. Fix that before worrying about the runtime error.

Comment: Mind elaborating on how I would do that?

Comment: Can you update your post to show your code (JavaApplication2.java)?

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you post a screen shot of _Java Platform Manager_ (**Tools > Java Platforms**)?

Comment: OK. Do **Run > Clean and Build Project (JavaApplication2)** and see whether you get **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** on the final line in the **Output** window which shows the result of the build. If not, is NetBeans indicating any errors in the source (with a red circle in the left margin of the source code)?

Comment: javac: invalid target release: 10.0  
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: [1] Select your project  in the **Projects** panel, right-click and select **Properties** from the menu. [2] Select **Libraries** and ensure that **Java Platform** is set to **JDK 10**. [3] Select **Sources** and ensure that **Source/Binary Format** is set to JDK 10. [4] Click **OK**. If you changed anything clean/build again.

Comment: Both of them were set to JDK 10. By the way thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: OK, more questions: [1] Is JDK 10 the only release of Java you have installed? If not, what else is installed? [2] Open a **Command Prompt** window and submit **java -version**. What version is displayed? Also, submit **set JAVA_HOME**. What is displayed? [3] Locate file **netbeans.conf** within the **etc** folder under the NetBeans installation folder, and open it in any text editor. Show the line containing **netbeans_jdkhome**, which should be near the end of the file. [4] Is this just a simple Java application created with the NetBeans project wizard? (i.e. Not a Maven project.)

Comment: java- version shows 10.0.2, my config file is good shows jdk 10.0.02, when I do set JAVA_Home it says Environment Variable JAVA_HOME not defined

Comment: That all sounds good. What about questions [1] and [4]? And just to double check, your **netbeans.conf** file shows **10.0.2** as the version, and not **10.0.02** as you posted above, right?

Comment: 4). Yes just a Java Application project. 1). I think there might be more jdks on this computer, how would I check them? The config file is set to 10.0.2.

Comment: Also I should note, there is Netbeans 8.2 on this computer as well, don't know if that is important or not.

Comment: [1] If you have NetBeans 8.2 then you almost certainly have JDK 8 installed, but none of that is a concern. In fact you can safely run NB 8.2 and NB 9.0 concurrently as as long as you don't open the same project in both of them at the same time. [2] Can you create the environment variable **JAVA_HOME** and set it to the value shown in your screen shot above in the **Platform Folder** field, then restart NetBeans 9.0 and retry the clean/build. [3] Just to double check, your **netbeans.conf** file shows **10.0.2** as the version, and not **10.0.02** as you posted above, right?

Comment: yes it shows 10.0.2. I created the variable JAVA_HOME and set the value to the platform folder field, reset, clean and build. Still have the same error.

Comment: OK, can you look in the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) to see if there are any relevant messages or stack traces? You only need to look at the entries since NetBeans was restarted.

Comment: Not seeing any stack traces? there are some warnings. Its a long log though.

Comment: Well the log shouldn't be that long since your most recent restart (hopefully!). One other thing to check is that your **PATH** environment variable only references JDK 10, and has no other older entries referencing (say) JDK 8. I don't think that matters anyway within NetBeans, but it can't hurt to clean it up. (I'm assuming you only care about using JDK 10 now.)

Comment: The log is pretty big! starting from the log session when I reset. How can I ensure my oath only references JDK 10?

Comment: [1] Re PATH, [this article](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) should tell you what to do. Just remove any entries referencing JDK releases other than JDK 10 from your path. [2] One other thing to try is to see if you can compile your app using **javac**. First, from the **Command Prompt** window, **cd** to the folder containing **JavaApplication2.java**. Then submit **javac JavaApplication2.java** to compile your app. There should be no response at all if all goes well, and file **JavaApplication2.class** should get created within your project. Can you try that?

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, is what I get when I try to run it from the Command Line.

Comment: Ahah! I had to clean up my path extensions in my system variable as you mentioned. I was able to execute javac, and my netbeans is now able to compile and successfully run. Thank you very much for taking time out of your day to walk me through this. Really Appreciate it!!

Comment: Cool. I still don't really understand why **java** worked from the command prompt for you, but **javac** did not, but it sounds like you have everything working now.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy, your JDK version is not 100 % compatible; use version 8.2, which is the most stable for Arduino and others.

To change platforms without deleting the existing one, simply go to Tools / Java Platforms / click on the button add Platforms.

Answer (score 0):

**Download/install JDK major version number the same as NetBeans.**

i.e. If You have NetBeans 9 version, but your JDK is version 10,So try use NetBeans 10 version... or download/install JDK 9 (the same as NetBeans).

**Create new java platform for new jdk installation.**

Open netbeans menubar->tools->Java Platforms->Add Platform Specify the folder that contains the Java platform as well as the sources and Javadoc needed for debugging.

**Set new java platform to your project**

Right click on project ->properties->Libraries->Java Platform->select the jdk version that same as NetBeans.

**Select source format of your project**

Right click on project ->properties->Sources->Sources/binary format->select the jdk version that same as NetBeans.

If it still give same error,Open the project properties, select the Build-Compiling, uncheck "Compile on save" and rerun the application. This will make sure all your source code becomes recompiled before running it.